# Spring Security with Spring Boot 3 - Get JWT token from Security Context Holder

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

After migrating to spring boot 3 ,

```
extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter is deprecrated.
```

Hence , unable to use the overrriden method

```
   @Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) {
    config.tokenServices(tokenServices());
}
```

I am able to replace this with

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth->auth.
            requestMatchers(whitelistedEndPoints()).permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .anonymous())
            .httpBasic().disable();
    return http.build();
}
```

I have an existing code to get jwt token from OAuth as

```
 public String getJwtTokenFromAuth() {
    OAuth2Authentication auth =(OAuth2Authentication) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
  
    OAuth2AuthenticationDetails oauth2AuthenticationDetails = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) auth.getDetails();
    return oauth2AuthenticationDetails.getTokenValue();
}
```

However,

> OAuth2Authentication and OAuth2AuthenticationDetails are not available

How can i replace this code/functionality with new spring security module of spring boot 3.
Below is the pom dependencies , please suggest if i need to add/remove any ?

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Security OAuth2 is deprecated and removed for a while. The replacement is built in Spring Security itself and the dependencies to use are exactly what you already know:

the required dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In order to gain the token value in a resource server you can do something like this

```
class PrincipalIntrospector {
    
    public String token() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        JwtAuthenticationToken oauthToken = (JwtAuthenticationToken) authentication;
        return oauthToken.getToken().getTokenValue();
    }
    
}
```

in order to make sure to have the role properly configured in your principal you can have something like below:

```
@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwt -> {
        List<String> authorities = jwt.getClaim("authorities");
        return authorities.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(toList());
    });

    return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
}
```

in order to decode and make to spring to validate your jwt you can configure something like below:

```
// used in case of public key
@Bean
public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(this.key).build();
}
// used in case of the private key
@Bean
public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(this.key).build();
}
```

The spring security pipeline can look like below:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(
        JwtDecoder  decoder,
        JwtAuthenticationConverter converter,
        HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth->auth.
                    requestMatchers(whitelistedEndPoints()).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().decoder(decoder).jwtAuthenticationConverter(converter);
    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: However keep in mind that for jwt token usually, you need the key to validate the token..... usually via JWK standard, with opaque you should need to introspect with the introspection oauth2 endpoint...... it means that you need to know the auth server url in any case

Comment: Never used for JWT use case in the new spring security support to embed the jwt signature key in the yaml configuration  but I know that now it should be possible

Comment: also had to convert string key to SecretKey object using below method   private SecretKey generateSecretKey() {
        SecretKey hmacKey;
        try {
            hmacKey = new SecretKeySpec("key".getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return hmacKey;
    }

Comment: This all seem very messy and not quite related to the question. For instance, neither client nor resource server should access JWTs private key, only the authorization server should. Plus, in case of an OpenID authorization server (the most frequent), the JWT decoder can be provided automatically by the framework.

Comment: JWTs should be base64 encoded, which does not require any key to encode / decode. The **private key** should be needed only to sign the JWT. A **public key** should be required on an OAuth2 resource server (for access tokens) or OpenID client (for ID tokens) only to validate the JWT signature, and this **public key** is generally available from the Authorization server JWK-set endpoint, which enables Spring Boot to setup JWT decoders `jwk-set-uri` property (optionnaly infered from `issuer-uri`). Look at my samples and tutorials, JWT decoders are always auto-configured.

Answer (score 2):

##### Why `OAuth2Authentication` isn't found by your IDE (and the compiler)

`OAuth2Authentication` was removed when migrating to Spring Security 5 back in september 2017. The default `Authentication` implementations for OAuth2 in Spring Security 6 (and 5) are:

- `JwtAuthenticationToken` resource server with JWT decoder (your case apparently as you depend on
  `spring-security-oauth2-resource-server` and expect a JWT)
- `BearerTokenAuthentication` for resource server with access token introspection (so called `opaqueToken` in configuration, even if you can introspect JWTs)
- `OAuth2AuthenticationToken` for clients

I wrote "default" because it is pretty easy to switch to other `Authentication` implementations for resource servers (but it's another subject).

##### Access `Authentication` in the security context

Either:

- use `SecurityContextHolder` static accessor, as you are already doing
- have it "magically" injected as `@Controller` method parameter (handy tooling to have the framework retrieve the `Authentication` in the security context holder for you)

Be aware that you may have an `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` in the security context
if the request authorization is missing or invalid (you can protect against that with access control rules like `isAuthenticated()`, `hasAuthority()`, etc.).

##### Code samples in a resource server with JWT decoder and default `Authentication` implementation

```java
var auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

if(auth instanceof JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuth) {
    final var jwt = jwtAuth.getToken();
    final var bearerString = jwt.getTokenValue();
    ...
}
```

```java
@RestController
public class MyController{
    @GetMapping("/public")
    public String mayGetTokenString(Authentication auth) {
        if(auth instanceof JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuth) {
            return jwtAuth.getToken().getTokenValue();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @GetMapping("/authorized")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()") 
    public String getTokenString(JwtAuthenticationtoken jwtAuth) {
        return jwtAuth.getToken().getTokenValue();
    } 
}
```

`JwtAuthenticationToken` might need to be replaced with something else in other configuration options (introspection, OAuth2 client, authentication converter returning custom authentication implementation)

##### P.S.

If discovering OAuth2 / OpenID with Spring Boot 3, you might find [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) helpful, and explanations why the configuration in the answer from @Valerio Vaudi is not optimal (definitely not a good idea to mix client and resource server configurations in a single security filter-chain).